# App run in background and open it again make device lag

Tags: android, lag

I have some problems to my app and I don't have any idea to fix that.

I open my app and use it for a while, then I let my app run in background which means I don't close it and use my phone do other things.

But when I want to use my app again, I found that my phone becomes very lag. When I click background app button to show which app is running in background, my app jumps to screen very lag, and when I want to click it or want to close it, it will very lag too, which means maybe my app make my phone become lag.

This situation only happen when I want to open my app again or I want to slide out my app to close it. When my app is running in background and I do other things, my phone will not lag.

I don't konw what happend to my app, can anyone tell me how can I check my app,
and know what happened that I can fixed it, thank you!

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: What is your app doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check in your application code that you have not put a heavy task on onResume() method. If possible try to take that execution in appropriate life cycle method.
- Put a break point on method which is call when the application got visible and try to find out that if any function is not taking much time to execution.